# FFXIV: Using XBox 360 Controller on PC

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, final-fantasy-14

How do you use an XBox 360 wireless controller in FFXIV on your PC?

You can set up all the configuration in `System Configuration`, but it doesn't seem to allow access to all the functions such as the weaponskill hotbar.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Character Configuration" under the System Menu. In the upper left, you'll see a switch to go from Mouse to Controller.